# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"1"'

Tags: python, integer

I'm attempting to create a bar chart using a csv file and I keep getting this message.
My data is almost all integers.

```
for item in text_list :
    pieces_list = item.strip().split(',')
    print(pieces_list)
    Month_list.append(pieces_list[0])
    Total_list.append(int(pieces_list[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The string `'"1"'` is three *separate* characters: `{ ", 1, " }`, and `"` is *not* valid in the context of evaluating an integer. This is no doubt caused by the CSV allowing quotes around a field:

```
"has quotes", does not have quotes, "1"
```

You need to strip off those double-quotes from the beginning and end of the string first (if they're there). For example:

```py
>>> withq = '"42"'

>>> int(withq)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"42"'

>>> int(withq.strip('"'))
42
```

---

Just keep in mind that this will strip all `"` characters from the start and end of a string, so `""""""""42"""` will still come through as `42`. And `replace()` will replace quotes *anywhere* in the string. To be absolutely safe, a better option would probably be a function to do the grunt work for you:

```py
# Get integer from a string CSV field.
# If first and last characters are both '"', convert the inner bit.
# Otherwise, convert the whole thing.
# May throw if bit being converted in not valid integer.

def csv_int(field):
    if len(field) >= 2 and field[0] == '"' and field[-1] == '"':
        return int(field[1:-1])
    return int(field)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I get the same error when doing

```
print(int('"1"'))
```

Notice the `"` surrounding the digit `1`.

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"1"'

So I suggest you use `replace()` on this string or something else to remove this occurrence.

```
print(int('"1"'.replace('"','')))
```

output

```
1
```